# What is the best nuclear missile crypto system?

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography

You are on a submarine and there is an encrypted message that you want to read. Two people must use their keys at the same time in order to obtain the plain text.  What is best cryptographic primitive to use?  Are the following two implementations suitable?

```
plain_text=decrypt(Key1 XOR key2,ciper_text,IV)

plain_text=decrypt(Key1,decrypt(key2,ciper_text,IV2),IV1)
```

(Assume AES-256-CBC with a CMAC block if it matters to you.)

Comment: Good question but the title may lead people to believe it’s not serious.

Comment: Unless you're actually on a nuclear sub, this sounds a lot like homework. And, if you _are_ on a nuclear sub, your employer has people working for them that can answer this question for you.

Comment: @paxdiablo I can dream!

Comment: Having read several other questions and answers about cryptography from The Rook, think we can be quite sure it's not homework. I rather think he is quite interested in the subject and likes to learn more.

Comment: How does calling `rc4_encrypt` on the cipher text help decrypt it? Is the call supposed to be `rc4_decrypt`, or does `decrypt` first apply `rc4_decrypt`, then another decryption algorithm?

Comment: This sounds dangerously like a homework assignment.  From another person...

Comment: @Jason Sometimes I wish I was still in school.

Comment: I deleted a reply accusing you of trying to get me to do your homework, once I saw the author :)  I think Nick Johnson below has your back on this topic.  I gave him a +1

Comment: @The Rook: You ask some of my favorite questions (even though I know you already know the answer..)

Comment: @Konrad actually, I found the title more challenging than the "how to require 2 keys to decrypt a message" variant.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111763/where-can-i-learn-about-proven-methods-for-sharing-cryptographic-keys

Answer (score 18, accepted):

XORing two randomly generated keys together to obtain the final secret is certainly secure. The general form of this is known as '[secret sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing)', and there are secure algorithms that allow you to generate 'm of n' schemes, where you generate n shares, and any m are sufficient to deduce the original key.

The best known scheme is [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir's_Secret_Sharing), and involves generating a random m-1 degree polynomial with the key as the constant, then sampling it at n locations, and giving those to the individuals as key shares.

Comment: Sometimes referred to as the 'k of n' problem (look at the terms in Shamir's algorithm and I bet you can guess why)

Answer (score 5):

By XORing the keys you're guaranteeing that every single bit in Key1 can potentially be modified by every single bit in Key2 (and vice-versa). It means that the holder of Key1 has no way of calculating either Key2 or the result of XORing Key1/Key2.

Another way of stating this is that the holder of Key1 would have to brute force every single possible combination of bits to exhaust the available keyspace.  The fact that he already holds one of the keys doesnt help him at all.

There are other ways of combining two keys together, but a simple XOR is all that is required when the keys are the same length.

Comment: It might be obvious, but it's maybe worth saying that both keys must be the same length :)

Comment: Agreed,  the keys would be the same length.

Answer (score 3):

Before thinking about solutions, you probably want to think about the requirements. In the given scenario, where you have two persons that are both needed to decrypt the message it is reasonable to require that

- each person never sees the key of the other person.

After all you want to avoid that one person just chooses a random ciphertext, pretends that this just came in, sees the key of the other person, and then notices that the ciphertext must have been a hoax.
This requirement makes the decryption with option 1 difficult.
Since you are using a MAC you probably also want that

- both persons are convinced that the decrypted message is legitimate.

This seems to rule out option 2. After all how can the holder of Key2 know that the holder of Key1 decrypted correctlty and did not just replace the legitimate plaintext with one of his choosing.

I must admit that I don't know a good solution for the scenario that you describe. A potential scheme might look like this: The ciphertext is tuple c1, c2, d1, d2, where

> c1 = EncryptAndMAC(Key1, Share1)
>
> d1 = MAC(Key2, hash(Share1))
>
> c2 = EncryptAndMAC(Key2, Share2)
>
> d2 = MAC(Key1, Share2)
>
> message = Share1 XOR Share2

Now both keys are needed to find the message, both parties can decrypt their shares independently without having to share their keys, and both parties can verify that the other party decrypted correctly. Of course, this is an ad-hoc protocol, so it is likely that I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

The second option:

```
plain_text=decrypt(Key1,decrypt(key2,ciper_text,IV2),IV1)
```

doesn't follow the requirement that both parties must use their keys at the same time. Key2 must be used before Key1, but once that happens, the first party (the possessor of Key1) can wait to decipher until a time of her choosing, leaving the second party out of the loop. This may or may not be a problem for the application.

As Cocowalla's Schneier quote suggests, XOR works, unless one of the parties can get the combined key (the decryptor may be able to keep this secret) and the other key has other uses. If the keys aren't statistically independent, the speed of XOR means the key combination step is vulnerable to guided brute-forcing (`decrypt` is still a bottleneck). If the keys are independent, then there's no need to figure out either partial key, nor does knowing one partial key help figure out the combined key, so a brute-force attack may as well target the combined key and ignore the parts. As caf mentions, figuring the other partial key is moot because it requires the combined key; also, you can only fire the nukes once. If one key is only used in combination with the other key (and we don't reuse passwords for different systems, right?), XOR is safe.

There are a couple of cryptographic systems that allow k-out-of-n keys to decrypt a message when used simultaneously, but I can't remember the term for them off the top of my head, and my copy of `Applied Cryptography` isn't at hand.

Edit: thanks to Cocowalla, the name of the scheme is "(m,n) threshold scheme". For a visual example, read "[Visual Cryptography and Bit-Plane Complexity Segmentation](http://www.drdobbs.com/security/201804177)" by Daniel Stoleru, published in Dr. Dobbs. [Visual cryptography](http://www.google.com/search?q=visual+cryptography) was created by Naor and Shamir, and presented at EUROCRYPT '94 (according to [Doug Stinson](http://www.cacr.math.uwaterloo.ca/~dstinson/visual.html)).

Wikipedia lists still more examples of [k-out-of-n secret sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secret_sharing): using n points, where the secret is an k-1 degree polynomial; using k k-hyperplanes, where the secret is the point of intersection.

Comment: 'Speed of XOR makes brute forcing more viable'. How so? You'll still be brute forcing every single possible combination of bits.

Comment: I think the term you are looking for is (m,n) _threshold scheme_ (i have access to my copy of Applied Cryptography ;) )

Comment: @PaulG: `decrypt` is still a potential bottleneck, but not key combination (hence "more viable" rather than "viable"). I should put the bit about independent/dependent keys back in. @Cocowalla: that sounds like the one. Does AC have the example using overlaid images that look like static?

Answer (score 0):

With this, I don't see how you could implement the requirement that any two people of sufficient rank - together - will be able to read the message...

Other than that: depending on the underlying encryption algorithm, having one half the XOR'ed key may allow one to derive parts of the complete key, significantly weakening the protection.

Then again, IANAC :)

Comment: Having one half of the XORd key gives you no information about the other half of the key, and subsequently no information about the complete key. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

XOR'ing the keys, while the simplist method, may not be the best. I don't think the resulting key would be random enough - if someone with key 1 was able to get their hands on the resulting key they may be able to derive key 2.

To throw further complexity into the mix, perhaps some kind of one-time pad would be a good plan. It's probably not a good idea to re-use keys for this kind of system :)

Here's an example of when reusing keys caused problems:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venona_project

**UPDATE**

I've just blown the dust off my copy of Bruce Schneier's excellent *[Applied Cryptography](http://www.schneier.com/book-applied.html)*, and taken a look at section 3.6 Secret Splitting. It's a different scenario, but he suggests that simply XOR'ing keys with a message is secure:

> Here’s a protocol in which Trent can split a message between Alice and Bob:
>
> (1) Trent generates a random-bit string, R, the same length as the message, M.
>
> (2) Trent XORs M with R to generate S.
>
> M ⊕ R = S
>
> (3) Trent gives
> R to Alice and S to Bob.

Note he says nothing of whether this might be suitable for a guarding a missile launch system ;)

Comment: There should be no correlation between `key1` and `key2` in *either* method - for example, both of them could simply be generated from a secure source of real random bits.  This is true in either case.

Comment: @caf what I mean is that (even with both keys being completely random) if one person has one of the keys, and the resulting XOR'd key, if may be possible for then to determine the other key - or have I still got it wrong?

Comment: If a person has one subkey and the resulting key then they can *definitely* determine the other subkey.  However since they already have the resulting key, this doesn't buy them anything.

Comment: Regarding Bruce's example: If R is *sufficiently* random, you are in effect using a One-time pad. Then, if either R or M is secret, it is *impossible* to get the other-half. Without the other half, it is impossible to get S. Reference: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-time_pad

Comment: @Jacco - It doesnt have to be an OTP to be 'sufficiently random'. It just means there shouldnt be a way to determine M from R

Comment: @PaulG correct. but, for it to be a One-Time Pad, it does have to be sufficiently random. If R (in the example) is truly random, the OTP is unbreakable. One-Time Pads are known to be used extensively by secret-services and military-intelligence around the world.

Comment: Oh I think I see what you are saying now, but I would avoid mentioning OTP's here. A OTP is (by definition) for use once only. This method of combining keys doesnt automatically make it a OTP, and infact if multiple messages use that key combination it is by definition *NOT* a OTP. Further, it could be confusing because a typical OTP could be as simple as XORing an encrypted message against a key of the same length. What we are discussing here is XORing *keys*.

Comment: I see your point. But: since the question is about a "nuclear missile crypto system", OTP is the very likely candidate for keeping the key secret. Each of the 2 people responsible holds 1 part of the XOR-ed key. combined, they have the key needed to access the system. Since this is 'nuclear missile system' level of security, all keys are for single use only.